# Запутался в переменных

Tags: python, tkinter

Начал пытатся в tkinter. Для начала хотел создать небольшую квест игру которая будет загадывать число а пользователь его отгадывает. Проблема в том, что лейбл при отгадывании накладывается один на другой, и я не понимаю как из одной функции удалить лейбл который обьявлен в другой. Переменная global тоже не помогает. Банальная ошибка, но я не пойму как  ее решить?

вот код.

```
import tkinter
import random

generate_number = random.randint(0, 10)

def game_logic():
    start_label.place_forget()
    if int(ent1.get()) < generate_number:
        number_so_small()
    elif int(ent1.get()) > generate_number:
        number_so_big()
    elif int(ent1.get()) == generate_number:
        number_is_correct()


def number_so_small():
    global lab1
    lab1 = tkinter.Label(text="загаданное число больше чем вы указали", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'))
    lab1.place(x=90, y=50)


def number_so_big():
    global lab
    lab = tkinter.Label(text='загаданное число меньше чем вы указали', font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'))
    lab.place(x=90, y=50)


def number_is_correct():
    lab.place_forget() //  вот тут ловлю ошибку
    lab1.place_forget() // и вот тут тоже нейм андефайнед
    correct = tkinter.Label(text="молодец!!!", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'))
    correct.place(x=180, y=50)


window = tkinter.Tk()
datatype = tkinter.IntVar()

entry_w = 480
entry_h = 320
screen_w = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_h = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry(f"{entry_w}x{entry_h}"
                f"+{int((screen_w / 2) - (entry_w / 2))}+{int((screen_h / 2) - entry_h)}")

start_label = tkinter.Label(text="Число сгенерировано, приступай!", font=("Arial", 16, 'bold'))
ent1 = tkinter.Entry(window, textvariable=datatype)
but1 = tkinter.Button(text="Ввести число", height=3, width=20, command=game_logic)

but1.place(x=160, y=220)
ent1.place(x=(entry_w / 2) - (5 * 13), y=170)
start_label.place(x=60, y=50)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: вы бы комментарии правильно оформляли ещё:-) #, а не //

Comment: извините, это я так на скорую руку

Comment: Видимо, в момент выполнения функции `number_is_correct` те две функции которые создают эти переменные ещё не отработали и переменные не создали.

Comment: Чтобы не путаться, создайте метку для сообщений один раз, и просто меняйте ее текст.

Comment: вы имеете в виду название переменной?

Comment: Я имею в виду один Label для всех сообщений. Создать ее один раз при старте программы, и только менять ее текст, а не создавать/удалять Label-ы для каждого сообщения. Тогда ничего не будет друг на друга накладываться (т.к. Label один), и проблем с удалением не будет (т.к. не нужно удалять).

Comment: вот теперь я понял спустя сутки свою ошибку, спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

Можете сделать например так, чтобы когда `lab` и `lab1` ещё не заполнены, метод `place_forget` не вызывался для них:

```py
lab = None
lab1 = None

...
def number_is_correct():
    if lab:
        lab.place_forget()
    if lab1:
        lab1.place_forget()
    correct = tkinter.Label(text="молодец!!!", font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'))
    correct.place(x=180, y=50)
```

Хотя это всё-равно выглядит как костыль, но работать должно.

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь, но все равно накладывается одна надпись на другую(

Comment: А, ну значит я неправильно понял проблему

Comment: если коротко то мне надо обратится к переменной lab и lab1 которые обьявлены в своих функциях из функции number_is_correct, а у меня не получается)

Comment: Да вроде получается. Если бы не получалось, выходила бы ошибка )

Comment: ну вот я в одной функции обьявил переменную, а как ее изменить в другой функции? У меня накладываются надписи одна на другую